# How can I prevent an application from closing in the background on Android 12?

Tags: android-12, google-pixel-6

I have a Pixel 6, and have the application "Fate/Grand Order" installed. On an earlier version of Android 12, the game would remain opened in the background, when the application was switched. That means, when I returned to it after e.g. looking something up on Chrome, the game would remain loaded, ready to proceed.

However, after updating Android 12 (*not* the game itself), the application would immediately close when switching to a different application. Returning to the game will cause it to start from the beginning.

How can I force Android to keep the game loaded in the background?

#### What I've tried

I have read in several sources that setting an app's battery usage to "Unrestricted" will cause the application to remain open in the background. I tried that, but the behavior did not change.

---

For information, my Pixel 6 has 8GB of RAM, and the developer options show that only 4.8 GB are used on average. So I *highly* doubt that the application is being closed out of a lack of RAM. Furthermore, Fate/Grand Order only requires 242 MB of RAM, while Chrome needs 337 MB.

Comment: *"How can I force Android to keep the game loaded in the background?"*. End user can't. Developer of the game can. Take logact when switching to other app to see why the app gets killed. If needed you can use my app [WhatsRunnig](https://github.com/mirfatif/WhatsRunning) to get a more broader picture of RAM usage.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the response. I ran logcat when launching and switching the application, but the output is *very* verbose. Any hints on what specifically I am looking for?

Comment: Look for "ActivityManager", your app's PID and  package name.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I've had a look around and ended up writing a bug report to the developers. It seems to be a bug with this specific unity version and this specific android version, so nothing even the devs can realistically do aside from upgrading.